# How to automatically join stripped pieces of video?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video, scene

I'm using Blender for non linear video editor, I'm simply removing dead times (times in which nothing happen) in my video using hard cut (<kbd>Shift + k</kbd>) after this process I've got something like this:[image]

At the moment I'm using  <kbd>g</kbd> for moving the pieces of video one by one next to each other for removing the black scene interruption is there an automatic way to do the same thing?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Keep the cursor (the green vertical line) on the left hand side, then <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Backspace</kbd> to remove all gaps. (If pressing <kbd>Backspace</kbd> once, it will only remove the first gap to the right of the current frame, which can be operate continously. This operation can be found at **Strip > Remove Gaps**)

[image]

**P.S.:**

Here, **Gap** means frame durations that don't hold any strips. So, in case of multiple channels, you may want to first select strips on particular channel, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> to make them as a temporary meta strip, then <kbd>Tab</kbd> into that Meta strip, do what you want to do. Then <kbd>Tab</kbd> again to exit meta group, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> to ungroup it.

Comment: This information is missing in the documentation: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/vse/sequencer/editing.html?highlight=gap#tools