# How to insert space or make a gab between many joined stripped pieces of Audio VSE?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

My question is the reverse process of this question: [How to automatically join stripped pieces of video?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7179/how-to-automatically-join-stripped-pieces-of-video)

I have many pieces of audio or clips that are joined together (eg: 20 clips). I need to make some space/gap between the fifth and the sixth clips so that I can insert another clip.

I downloaded the power sequencer Plugin but I'm not sure if it can do it or not.

What's the easiest way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two fast methods:

#### First method

Inside the VSE, deselect all strips then, press <kbd>b</kbd> and drag your mouse to box select the strips you want to move. When you have selected them, press <kbd>g</kbd> to grab all of them and move them by the desired amount with your mouse. Finish with <kbd>LMB</kbd>.

#### Second method

Inside the VSE, place your cursor inside the strip after which you want to insert the gap with <kbd>LMB</kbd>. Then select *Strip* -> *Insert Gaps* or press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> and it will insert a gap after the current strip. This is actually the reverse of the method mentioned in the question you linked.

Hope that helps.

Comment: The _Insert Gaps_ menu item works for me, but `Shift+=` doesn't do anything. Is this keyboard map dependent? On my keyboard, `Shift+=` is `+`.

Comment: The shortcut doesn't work for me either with a German keyboard layout.